# Custom Clone Lightning Component Quick Action not working

Tags: lightning-aura-components, clone

I'm attempting to use this to create a clone of an Opp. It's set map over two fields. But I can't get it to work. It will only produce a blank square dialog box when the action is used.

Here are the different pieces.

**Component :**

```
<aura:component controller="CloneOpp" implements="force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,lightning:actionOverride,force:hasRecordId">
    <ltng:require styles="/resource/SLDS202/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.css"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />
    <aura:attribute name="oppName" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="typePick" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="campaign" type="String" />
  
     <aura:dependency resource="c:createRecord"/>
    <!-- Load the navigation events in the force namespace. -->
    <aura:dependency resource="markup://force:*" type="EVENT"/>
    
    
</aura:component>
```

**Controller :**

```
({
     doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
      //call the helper function with pass [component, Controller field and Dependent Field] Api name 
     // alert('Hi');
      helper.queryOpp(component, event, helper);
   },
   
})
```

**Helper :**

```
({
    queryOpp: function(component,  event, helper) {
      var recordId = component.get("v.recordId");
        if(recordId!=undefined){
        
        
        alert(recordId);
        var action = component.get("c.getDetailsFromOpp");
        action.setParams({
            recordId: recordId
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
           
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                var opp = response.getReturnValue();
                component.set("v.oppName", opp.Name); 
                component.set("v.typePick", opp.pcikListTest__c);
                component.set("v.campaign", opp.CampaignId);
               
                helper.createOppRecord(component, event, helper);
              
            }
           
        });
        
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
        }
    },
     createOppRecord : function (component, event, helper) {
       var name=  component.get("v.Name"); 
       var picklist = component.get("v.typePick"); 
        var campaign=  component.get("v.campaign");
        // alert(picklist);
       //  alert(campaign);
    var createOpportunityEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
    createOpportunityEvent.setParams({
    "entityApiName": "Opportunity",
    "defaultFieldValues": {
        'Name' : 'New Opp',
        'Type' : 'Existing Customer - Upgrade',
        'pcikListTest__c' : picklist,
        'CampaignId' : campaign
        }
    });
    createOpportunityEvent.fire();
    },
    
})
```

**Class :**

```
public class CloneOpp {
 @AuraEnabled 
    public static Opportunity getDetailsFromOpp(string recordId){
       Opportunity opp = [select Id,Name,CampaignId,TrackingNumber__c,pcikListTest__c
        from Opportunity Where Id = :recordId limit 1];
       return opp ;
    }

}
```

Does anything stand out as out of place ? Any help you can give would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: This is not an LWC

Comment: Oh, when I created it in Dev Console I created it as a Lightning Component. I guess I left something out ? What have I left out ? I don't think I chose Quick Action as the type, but will this code work as a Quick Action ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: To be clear this is a Lightning Aura Component, aka Lightning Component or Aura component, not an LWC. Aura is the older technology, though necessary to use for custom actions at this point. I am simply saying you need to change the title and tagging of this question.

Comment: Thank you @PhilW - I changed the title of the question. Do you see anything wrong with the coding ? I'm assuming I set it up correctly since the only choice is "Lightning Component".

Comment: I added ",force:hasRecordId" to the component and now it's working - kinda. I'm being prompted with an error which says "Access Check Failed! AttributeSet.get(): attribute 'Name' of component 'markup://c:CloneOpp_beta {32:6771;a}' is not visible to 'markup://c:CloneOpp_beta {32:6771;a}'." - once I close that error the rest works as it should. Any idea on that error ?

Comment: I suspect it is ```createOppRecord```'s ```var name=  component.get("v.Name");``` failing because the ```queryOpp``` function uses ```component.set("v.oppName", opp.Name);``` (oppName, not Name).

Comment: That was it. Thanks a bunch @PhilW !